# Pesquisa ajax com laravel 5.6 e jquery

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Estou com problemas para executar uma pesquisa ajax com laravel, segue o código ajax da minha view:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#enviarForm').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#filtro').serialize();

    $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
          $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "{{url('/cadastro')}}",
            data: form,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              alert('ola');
            }
          });
  });
});
```

Código do controller:

```
if($request->ajax()){
        $nome = $request['ds_paciente'];
    $Pessoas=\App\Pessoas::where('ID_CD_TIPOPESSOA',1)
                           ->where('IN_STATUS',1)
                           ->where('NM_PESSOA', 'LIKE', '%' . $nome . '%')
                            ->paginate(10);

    return view('todosPacientes',compact('Pessoas'));
    }
```

Estou um pouco perdido e não estou encontrando tutoriais na internet.

Comment: Tens algum erro? Ou o que acontece? O formulário `#filtro` tem o campo `ds_paciente`?

Comment: O erro é que nada acontece, simplesmente não funciona, os campos estão corretos

Comment: Poste o código do seu html/blade também

Comment: tentou `$request->input('ds_paciente')`

Comment: Mano, primeiro se você quer retorno usando Ajax, no controller tem que ser: return Response::json($Ponsulta);